# crontab doesn't execute my python script

Tags: python, cron

I'm trying to add my python script into cron so it executes every minute

This is my python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env  python
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import zipfile
import os.path
from time import sleep
import csv
import re
import urllib
import os

class Tor_class:
    def __init__(self, s ,ip_tor_file,name):
            url = ip_tor_file

            request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={"Accept" : "text/html"})
            webFile = urllib2.urlopen(request)

            localFile = open(url.split('/')[-1], 'w')
            localFile.write(webFile.read())
            webFile.close()
            localFile.close()
            self.name_ = name
            self.counter = 0


def updateDB():

    ip_Tor = Tor_class('\n','''http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/ip_list_exit.php/Tor_ip_list_EXIT.csv''',"Tor")
    os.rename('Tor_ip_list_EXIT.csv','Tor_ip_list_EXIT.txt')


 if __name__ == "__main__":
    updateDB()
```

when I put this script in cron by using crontab -e

```
*       *       *       *       *       /tmp/download.py
```

It doesn't do anything.

It is all works just fine when I do it in a commend line like that:

```
$ /tmp/download.py
```

Does anyone have a clue why It doesn't work?

Comment: Your filenames use relative paths; are you *certain* it didn't work? The files are written in whatever directory cron set as the current working dir.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes that's important to know. (although he don't uses filesystem operation as far as shown).. I think the working directory of a script executed by cron will be `/`

Comment: So where should I see the file when cron run the script?

Comment: What evidence do you have that it didn't do anything? Have you examined cron's log files? Try adding a print statement after the hash-bang and before the imports, then examine the user's email and/or the cron logfiles.

Comment: @roihatam, I'm not sure if it's standard, but my `cron` uses the user's home directory for it's CWD.  That being said, my cron lines are typically something like: `* * * * * cd /path/to/working-dir/; python /path/to/executable-script.py` -- the `cd` changes the cwd and is the base for any relative file operations inside the script

Comment: We are getting into System Administration... This would better be placed over in ServerFault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have an odd indentation in the line with `if __name__ ==...` - guess you should check it in your script. Then, make sure with what current directory your script runs, AFAIK it is your $HOME - this is where the file would appear.